# Почему GC Golang не чистит ресурсы?

Tags: golang, сборщик-мусора

Есть сервер, который выполняет скачивание данных с API, обработку и занесение в БД.
Для каждого запроса на скачивание создаётся отдельный слайс структур, в который записываются значения, затем частями вставляются в БД.

Проблема в том, что после запроса на скачивание к примеру 500к значений объём используемой озу становится ~250МБ и больше не уменьшается, даже если вручную запустить runtime.GC(). Вроде никакие функции не эскейпят этот слайс структур

Что самое странное, так это то, что при повторных запросах количество используемой ОЗУ больше не растёт если эти запросы <= по объему данных. 
Что то похожее на буфер

---

На каждый запрос в функции fetchData создаётся слайс структур:

```
result := mytypes.InitKlNums(workers)
```

Сама функция:

```
func InitKlNums(count int64) *[]KlNum {
klArr := make([]KlNum, 0, count)

for i := int64(0); i < count; i++ {
    klArr = append(klArr, KlNum{
        Num:  i,
        List: make([]Kline, 0, 500),
        Len:  0,
    })
}
return &klArr
}
```

Запрос обрабатывается воркерами, которым передаются такие значения:

```
go worker(&wg, times[i-1], times[i], symbol, interval, &(*result)[i-1])
```

То есть каналы не используются, вроде утечки горутин и памяти в них не должно происходить из-за блокирования.

Дальше fetchData возвращает result основному хэндлеру запроса, который делает INSERT полученных значений в БД

Сумбурно описал, прошу не кидаться тапками

Comment: Гошный сборщик мусора по-разному возвращает (или не возвращает) память в ОС. Если хотите зафорсить это вручную, используйте [`runtime/debug.FreeOSMemory`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#FreeOSMemory).

Comment: [Вон там](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#runtime) ещё про `MADV_FREE` почитайте.

Comment: @Ainar-G  FreeOSMemory тоже не выполняет освобождение, так и висит. Сама освобождается через какое то время (в районе получаса).

Comment: @Ainar-G и да, на линуксе сервак. Насколько я понял при MADV_FREE ОЗУ освобождается только тогда, когда её станет не хватать и ОС попросит её обратно?

Comment: Типа того. Рекомендую, если большой RSS не мешает никому, ничего и не трогать.